# Ubuntu 17.04 desktop not loading

Tags: dual-boot, 17.04, .desktop

I've had Ubuntu 17.04 working for a few weeks along with Windows 10 since my computer supports dual boot.

When I started my computer and tried to login the background went black and only my cursor appeared.

I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open a terminal but while I'm using it the desktop appears to be trying to load again and again so I have to go back to the terminal every few seconds.

For now the only thing that I've tried is reinstalling `lightdm`, but it didn't fix the problem.

What should I do to fix this problem?